# QThread to send large queries to the database

Tags: qt4

I have created this class that inherits from QThread for send data to the database server, what do you think about it? Could be impreved?

Thanks

```
#ifndef QUERYTHREAD_H
#define QUERYTHREAD_H

#include 

class QSqlQuery;

class QueryThread : public QThread {
    public slots:
        bool exec(QSqlQuery *query, Priority priority=InheritPriority);
    protected:
        virtual void run();
    private:
        bool m_hasError;
        QSqlQuery *q;
};

#endif // QUERYTHREAD_H
```

```
#include "querythread.h"

#include 
#include 

bool QueryThread::exec(QSqlQuery *query, Priority priority)
{
    q=query;
    start(priority);
    while(isRunning()) qApp->processEvents();
    return m_hasError;
}

void QueryThread::run()
{ m_hasError=q->exec(); }
```

Answer (score 3):

A couple of opinions:

That `while` loop in `exec` elimiates the advantages of having a separate thread. You should pass the query in at the constructor, have one thread per query, **don't** override `exec`, prefer to just use [start](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qthread.html#start) and use signals to asynchronously report any error.

You should also pass the QSqlQuery by value or store it in a managed pointer such as `std::auto_ptr` (or `std::unique_ptr` for C++11). Many Qt classes are [implicitly shared](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/implicit-sharing.html) (although not this one) but managed pointers gain you exception safety.

Personally, I would have simply done something like this

```
class Query : public QThread {

    QSqlQuery m_query;
    // I prefer values unless there's a particular reason to use pointers.

public:

    Query (const QSqlQuery & query)
    : m_query (query)
    {
    }

    void run ()
    {
        emit finished (m_query .exec ());
        deleteLater ();
    }

public signals:

    void finished (bool);
};

Query * q = new Query ("SELECT foo FROM bar");

connect (q, SIGNAL (finished (bool), ...);

q -> start ();
```